# Live Server - Live Reload function doesn't work on WSL with different directories path

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, livereload

The problem is simple, I have my index.html in the parent directory and the CSS files in the CSS folder, while I have this folder configuration the live server extension in vs code doesn't auto reload the changes when the CSS file is saved inside a folder , when is in the same directory as the html file works fine.

This error only happens with the WSL2, and also happens with JavaScript files.

Edit: Yes the files are on the Windows filesystem, I have the symlink to the windows folder in my wsl.

Comment: Are your files in Widnows drive or WSL file system ?

Comment: @Philippe is probably on the right track here.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455155/11810933) for more information, a likely reason why it is occurring, and how to fix.

Comment: according to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402588/how-can-nodemon-be-made-to-work-with-wsl-2/63455155#63455155) the best option is moving the file to the wsl filesystem right?