# --watch not working after updateing from webpack 4 to 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webpack-5

I have been migrating a project from Webpack 4 up to 5 and have hit a snag. The `--watch` option is no longer working with my configuration, and I've tried everything I can find.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const PATHS = {
  build: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
}

const baseConfig = {
  entry: {
    main: './js/router.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: `[name].[chunkhash].js`,
    chunkFilename:`[name].[chunkhash].js`,
    publicPath: '/dist'
  }
  //loaders and stuff
}

module.exports = baseConfig;
```

`webpack --watch --progress --mode development`

This is what the config can be boiled down to cause the issue. Webpack builds initially fine and I can view the page locally.
[image]

But any further changes to the entry point or any modules it imports does not recompile. The progress option I added to the start command has no effect.

I suspect the issue lies with WSL. When I upgraded to webpack 5, I encountered [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/187)
For some reason webpack 5 tries to scan system files if it is located in `/mnt/c` and gets locking errors. I ended up settling on [this](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/187#issuecomment-821622126) answer and moving where my project was located from `/mnt/c/dev` to `/usr/local/dev`. This solved the locking issue, and here I am now.

I have also tried adding to my webpack config:

```
watchOptions: {
    poll: true
}
```

and also tried playing around with different polling times. Nothing gave me different results.

Comment: WSL1 or WSL2?  WSL2 should *not* have worked on `/mnt/c/dev`, but *should* work on `/usr/local/dev` (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455155/11810933) for more details).  Although, polling should work around the issue, so I'm just not sure what you're facing.  Also, just a side-note, you might think "/usr" stands for "user", but it actually is an abbreviation for "unix system resources".  IMHO, it is really *not* the place to store project files.  Those should be in something like `$HOME/src` or something.

Comment: I am on WSL 1, I have heard mixed things about 2 and didn't want to update. I'm kind of out of troubleshooting ideas at this point.

I did have this misconception about the usr dir, thank you. I once googled what location would be best practice to put various scripts or server deployments and I remember `/usr/local` being recommended.

Comment: Agreed - With your use case, WSL1 is probably the better fit.  WSL1 and WSL2 both have their benefits and drawbacks, so I keep both around.  I'll noodle on the `--watch` issue -- I just haven't come across any questions like that so far on WSL1, and no ideas pop to mind immediately.  Re: usr -- I've been using Linux casually for a couple of decades and I always thought that naming was strange, also mentally pronouncing it "user", but knowing it contained system files.  Only recently did I come across a mention of it being an acronym myself.