# npm watch suddenly stopped working on WSL

Tags: vue.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My project is built using Symfony and Vue. I run this project locally inside WSL 2. Whenever I run `npm run watch` it runs `encore dev --watch` and it compiles everything successfully, however, if I make any changes to my code it does not update anymore. It used to work fine and it suddenly stopped working a few days ago. All I can think of is that my Windows got an update but not sure if it can be related. I removed a check for fast startup because I saw some people had issues with it. Anyone else had a similar problem or know what could be the case? Attaching the output of `npm run watch` command, `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` if that helps.

P.S. I setup this project on MacOS and the watch works perfectly there.

npm run watch output

```
> watch
> encore dev --watch

Running webpack ...

 RECOMMEND  To create a smaller (and CSP-compliant) build, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/vuejs.html#runtime-compiler-build
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 16677ms                                                                                                                                     4:47:59 PM

8 files written to public/build
Entrypoint app [big] 2.63 MiB = runtime.js 14.6 KiB vendors-node_modules_core-js_internals_array-species-create_js-node_modules_core-js_internals-076afc.js 150 KiB vendors-node_modules_symfony_stimulus-bridge_dist_index_js-node_modules_bootstrap_dist_js_boo-0f0115.js 1.78 MiB app.css 682 KiB app.js 21.5 KiB
Entrypoint player [big] 3.6 MiB = runtime.js 14.6 KiB vendors-node_modules_core-js_internals_array-species-create_js-node_modules_core-js_internals-076afc.js 150 KiB vendors-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_array_concat_js-node_modules_vue-loader_dist_exportHe-c2d964.js 3.34 MiB player.js 103 KiB
Entrypoint _tmp_copy 14.6 KiB = runtime.js
webpack compiled successfully
```

webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('player', './assets/js/player.js')
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableVueLoader()
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|)$/
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
        "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^3.2.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "core-js": "^3.23.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "glob-all": "^3.3.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.4",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
        "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "sass": "^1.59.2",
        "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
        "vue": "^3.3.4",
        "vue-loader": "^17.3.0",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you could include all relevant code and error messages as text, and not as screenshots so your question can be more easily found by others encountering the same issue!

Comment: @0xLogN Hiya! Thank you, I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of `inotify`-based tools (such as the `--watch` functionality) not working on WSL is that the project is located on (or was moved to) the Windows filesystem.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455155/11810933) for details on the root cause.

The second reason would be a change in the WSL version.  If you previously used WSL1, it would have worked there.  However, this limitation in the Plan9 driver is unique to WSL2.  I can't think of any way that a recent Windows upgrade would have changed this, though.

If either of those are the reason for the change you've seen, the solutions are similar to the ones I mention in the linked answer:

- Use a polling-based mechanism if the tool you are using supports it.
- Move the project to the Linux filesystem inside WSL (much faster as well)
- Downgrade to WSL1